# Como deixar o background de uma <div> fixo no Safari do iOS (iPad)?

Tags: html, css

Tenho um layout que funciona muito bem no desktop, mas ao visualizar no Safari do iOS (iPad especificamente) ele não aparece como esperado. Eu quero que o background da div permaneça fixo ao rolar a página. Alguém sabe como corrigir esse problema?

## css

```
#caixa{
    background:url(imagem.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;      
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
}
```

## html

```
<div id="caixa"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade, o seu background está fixo. O problema é o "viewport"...

> Primeiro, vamos recapitular por que o posicionamento fixo não funciona
>   como esperado. O Safari Mobile usa um "viewport" para mostrar websites.
>   Imagine um livro diante de você. Pegue um pedaço de papel, corte um
>   quadrado 320×416 no mesmo, e coloque o papel com o quadrado aberto
>   no meio sobre o livro. Para ler o livro, mova o papel e posicione o
>   buraco sobre as palavras que você quer ver. Isso é exatamente o que o
>   "viewport" do Safari Mobile está fazendo. Quando você toca e arrasta,
>   você está movendo o "viewport" por sobre o site, que continua estático
>   "abaixo" dele.
>
> Isso faz com que o posicionamento fixo se torne nulo e inútil no
>   iPhone. Um elemento que tem posicionamento fixo está afixado ao
>   `body`, e não ao `viewport`. Ou seja: o `fixed` está atualmente
>   funcionando como desejado, apesar de que gostaríamos que estivesse
>   *afixado* ao "viewport".

fonte: http://old.doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/

Comment: Foi o que eu imaginei, pois nenhum site que utiliza este recurso estava funcionando corretamente no iPad. Obrigado.

Comment: Após uma rápida pesquisa, me parece que a opção "snap" da biblioteca iScroll consegue contornar o problema: http://iscrolljs.com/#snap - boa sorte!

Answer (score 0):

@PauloMaciel,

deixe seu id assim:

```
#caixa{
  background:url(imagem.jpg) no-repeat;      
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Ou tente:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
  #caixa{
    background:url(imagem.jpg) no-repeat;      
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
  }
}
```

Comment: Continua apresentando o mesmo problema no iPad.

Comment: Esta testando com simulador ou dispositivo mesmo?

Comment: Estou testando no próprio iPad, já tentei de várias formas solucionar mas o problema persiste, inclusive sites que utilizam este recurso também não funcionam no iPad.

Answer (score -1):

Já testou em outro iPad? Tem certeza que não é um erro do teu iPad. Uma vez tive um problema de visualização de margem no firefox. Fiz de tudo e nada. Então em outro pc que tinha só o chrome (e a porcaria do IE) eu instalei o firefox e funcionou bem. Não sei o que causou o problema no meu firefox, eu tinha windows7. Por outros motivos eu tirei o windows e passei a usar linux (que o firefox é padrão) e agora o firefox não apresenta aquele erro. Talvez seja algo parecido com o teu iPad.

Comment: Não é um problema do meu iPad, iOS é diferente de Windows, esse comportamento é padrão nesse sistema.